Why this VBA macro creates a VBA project?
I need to import a csv file, but VBA/Excel is very bad at formatting it. The only way I found is to first copy the file as .txt then import it with Workbooks.OpenText.
Here is the code (functional and good).
Sub CopierDonneesDepuisCSV()
' Convert .csv into a .txt, import .txt then delete it
' Usefull when Excel doesn't know how to parse csv...

    Dim Newsheet As String
    Newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("fileDate").Value 'path file
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets(templateSheet)
    ws.Copy After:=ws
    ActiveSheet.Name = Newsheet
       
    With Worksheets(Newsheet)
        .Range("B4").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("filePath").Value
        .Range("B5").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("fileDate").Value
        .Range("B6").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("commentaire").Value
        .Range("B7").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("auteur").Value
        .Range("B8").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("hash").Value
        .Range("B11").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("nbGen").Value
        .Range("B12").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("timeout").Value
        .Range("B13").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("efficiency").Value
        
        ' Creating the .txt file
        Dim data_csv As Workbook
        pathTxt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("filePath").Value & ".txt"
        FileCopy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("filePath").Value, pathTxt
        
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=pathTxt, Comma:=True, DataType:=1, TrailingMinusNumbers:=False
        Set data_csv = ActiveWorkbook
    
        data_csv.Sheets(1).Range("A2:K60").Copy
        .Range("E16:O100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        data_csv.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A60").Copy
        .Range("A17:A100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        data_csv.Close False
        ' Deleting the .txt file
        Kill ThisWorkbook.Sheets(importSheet).Range("filePath").Value & ".txt"
    End With
    Call ImportTextFile
    
End Sub

The problem is that this code creates an empty VBAproject every time I run the macro, named after the .txt file.

Why is it creating a project?
I tried to delete "VBAProject", "Microsoft Excel Objects" and "Feuill1" with right-click, but I cannot. How do I delete them?



Every time you open a workbook, it contains a project, an empty project. When you close them it takes a little time to be removed from the Viewer. Your workbook.opentext is where the project is created, its a normal thing.

You're right, 2 days later now, opening and checking again, the empty workbooks have been removed.
@ricardoA can you post an answer, so I can accept it ?
